# Making paths and roads work together with ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, ordnance-survey

Working in Arc GIS 10 .0 service pack 5, network analyst extension, Productivity Suite 2.1 service pack 7, on Windows 7.

I am trying to get the Ordnance survey ITN urban paths layer to work with OS ITN roads to model pedestrian journeys. I've had a ton of problems doing this mainly related to the sofware that unpacks the OS raw data, but I think (?) it finally unpacked it OK and my problem is in Network Analyst in Arc.

I've got threads on a bunch of forums and I think I'm inching towards a soloution. I need nearest facility and service areas that are based on connections across both paths and roads in a network. I had a network that would do solves but only on paths or roads but no connectivity between them (the connectivity properties were fine though).

From other advice I got I found there were two problems here, firstly a bug in Productivty Suite which the service pack (and a reinstall) got around.

Secondly I'd not integrated the two layers - so I did this using the integrate tool without crashing or errors, although I'm not sure I've done it right - I just integrated the path links and road links - not sure if I need to select all of the nodes as well and integrate the lot?

Assuming I have done this correctly, I now try a simple route solve to test the data that have been unpacked and integrated and I get an error message that says it is "unable to create a network anlalysis layer because the network data set has no cost attributes".  Not sure where my cost attributes went or what to do about this. Incidentally I'm not doing anything very sophisticated with costs, I simply want a bunch of nearest facilities and service areas based on walk distances in metres - no parameters use of hierarchies or anything.

I've got the technical paper from the OS on using Connecting Links in Urban Paths.

Has anyone out there made these data work together?